# Dynamic Procedure BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Does Bigquery support dynamic procedure calls? I am looking to generate a procedure name as string based on variables and call the string.

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` returns this error clearly it doesn't support CALL. Is there any other way?
SQL created by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` contains unsupported statement type: `CallStatement`.

Thank you.

Comment: you can create one proc that will branch logic depends on passed  argument - so kind of multiple procs in one!

Comment: Do you mean using if/else to call a procedure based on passed values from another procedure?

Comment: Sure. You should try

Comment: props to that comment!, indeed that is how it should go for now. As show in the documentation for [execute_immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) `calls` are not supported on dynamic query. If you post an answer mikhail I will thumb up!.

Answer (score 0):

I make this answer for visibility, the approach you can use is as follow (as mention in the comments by mikhail):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `project-id.dataset`.maker(option INT64)
BEGIN
IF option=1  THEN
    CALL `project-id.dataset`.create_user(); #call to procedure
  ELSEIF option=2 THEN
    CALL `project-id.dataset`.create_customer(); #call to procedure
ELSE 
  SELECT "END"; #default
END IF;
END
```

to use

```
CALL `project-id.dataset`.maker(2)
```

As stated in the comments, [execute immediate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) do not support at the moment the usage of `call`.
I also found a `feature request` about [supporting using call with execute immediate](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198741726) on google issue tracker you can leave a comment to support the feature request.

Comment: thanks. the issue is i want to use a table which list n number of procedures and execute them in the order provided in the table. This procedure will act like a scheduler driven by the table. 1,2 option wont work in this case.

Comment: On tha case, I recommend to use python to perform the calls to a procedure based on a control table. A batch file will make the call to your python file and then make a call to your table to get your control table data and then perform your control table  procedure operation. Right now, `Call within a Call` is not supported.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer and supporting the feature request link. The issue you mention will be out of the scope of your main question.